# Next.js webpack changes are added in git changes

Tags: reactjs, git, webpack, next.js

Why on my git changes this files are added? I cannot find solution for this and reason. Also adding to .gitignore does not help. Thanks in advance for any tips on that!

[image]

I tried to add to .gitignore, update next, clear cache

```
    # Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules
jspm_packages

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history
.next``

.next/
.next
.next/cache
.next/cache/images/XRLy2mj54hjpCmhHptAEqpb2WAUeGZGkZ7YPqY1zd7w=/60.1702714879042.Yhst-HY-v0t4UaR56ciP57mFAJtqv4BZZ5OqWkE94F8=.webp
*.js
.next/static/chunks/webpack.js
```

Each time i push commit and run the app the new changes (.next/cache/webpack are added to my git changes) even though i never touch this files

Comment: Show your .gitignore, please

Comment: @Nokkond I added my .gitignore

Comment: Does your .gitignore works fine with other written directories? is it in the root of your project?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the folder was commited at some point and now it's in the staging area. You first need to remove it from the staging area and then it will be ignored.

Try this:

- Be sure that you have on your `.gitignore` the folder `.next` or whatever you want to avoid commiting.
- Run the following command to remove `.next/` from the staging area: `git rm -r --cached .next/`

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons why files might still be included.

For files already committed:

```
git rm --cached <file_or_directory>
```

This good to untrack files or directories in a Git repository without deleting them.

For global git Ignore:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile
```

or

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

This is useful for checking the path of the global Git ignore file on your system. Replace ~/.gitignore_global with the path to the file you want to use as your global Git ignore file.

It might also be a caching issue. If it is, this should fix it for you. It removes all files and directories from the staging area and adds them afterwards:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to your gitignore:

```
/.next/
```

Comment: I added it and I still can see those files

Answer (score -1):

I think because you have commited the whole `.next` folder, so now they're tracked by git, even if you add the folder to `.gitignore` file.

To fix this, you would need to:

1. Make a backup of your code
2. Add the template .gitignore below
3. Delete the folder from your local
4. Clear git cache: `git rm -r --cached .next/`
5. Commit change
6. Restore/Reinstall your packages

For Next.js, here is the recommended .gitignore file by [Toptal](https://github.com/toptal/gitignore/tree/master/templates)

```
### NextJS ###
# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# next.js
/.next/
/out/

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
*.pem

# debug
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
.pnpm-debug.log*

# local env files
.env*.local

# vercel
.vercel

# typescript
*.tsbuildinfo
next-env.d.ts
```

You can also stack multiple project type using some gitignore generator tool online, like [this](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore) one

Comment: Recommended by whom? Please provide a resource link if this is in documentation somewhere.

Comment: even with this .gitignore i can still have this files from above